# obtaining cv::Scalar from cv::Mat of unknown type

Tags: c++, opencv

after reading an image of unknown depth and channel number i want to access its pixels one by one.

on opencv 1.x the code goes:

```
IplImage * I = cvLoadImage( "myimage.tif" );
CvScalar pixel = cvGet2D( I, y, x );
```

but on opencv 2.x the `cv::Mat.at()` method demands that i know the image's type:

```
cv::Mat I = cv::imread( "myimage.tif" );
if( I.depth() == CV_8U && I.channels() == 3 )
    cv::Vec3b pixel = I.at<cv::Vec3b>( x, y );
else if( I.depth() == CV_32F && I.channels() == 1 )
    float pixel = I.at<cv::float>( x, y );
```

is there a function resembling `cvGet2D` that can receive `cv::Mat` and return `cv::Scalar` without knowing the image's type in compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For someone who is really a beginner in C++ ...

***... and/or a hacker who just need to save mere seconds of code typing to finish off [the last project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89variste_Galois)***

---

```
cv::Mat mat = ...; // something
cv::Scalar value = cv::mean(mat(cv::Rect(x, y, 1, 1)));
```

---

*(Disclaimer: This code is only slightly less wasteful than a young man dying for a revolutionary cause.)*

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. There's no such function in the C++ API.

The rationale behind this is performance. `cv::Scalar` (and `CvScalar`) is the same thing as `cv::Vec<double,4>`. So, for any `Mat` type other than `CV_64FC4`, you'll need a conversion to obtain `cv::Scalar`. Moreover, this method would be a giant `switch`, like in your example (you have only 2 branches).

But I suppose quite often this function would be convenient, so why not to have it? My guess is that people would tend to overuse it, resulting in really bad performance of their algorithms. So, OpenCV makes it just a tiny bit less convenient to access individual pixels, in order to force client code to use statically typed methods. This isn't such a big deal convenient-wise, since more often than not, you actually know the type statically and it's a really big deal performance-wise. So, I consider it a good trade-off.

Comment: Agreed. But the lack of this feature would stumble a lot of C++ beginners, considering that this would require beginners to write a dynamic-to-template pixel type dispatch function if they want to process both grayscale and color images.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I just wanted to test something quickly and performance was not an issue. But all parts of the code uses `cv::Mat()`. What I did was the following

```
Mat img;  // My input mat, initialized elsewhere

// Pretty fast operation, Will only create an iplHeader pointing to the data in the mat
// No data is copied and no memory is mallocated. 
// The Header resides on the stack (note its type is "IplImage" not "IplImage*")
IplImage iplImg = (IplImage)img;

// Then you may use the old (slow converting) legacy-functions if you like
CvScalar s = cvGet2D( &iplImg, y, x );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a warning: you are using cvLoadImage and imread with default flags. This means that any image you read will be a 8-bit 3-channel image. Use appropriate flags (IMREAD_ANYDEPTH / IMREAD_ANYCOLOR) if you want to read image as is (which seems to be your intention).